# Image changing while pressed

Tags: image, swing, mouseevent, jcomponent

I have 2 images for a JComponent, one of an unpressed button, and one of a pressed button. When I click the button, I want the image to change for the pressed one, but only while  I am clicking. Which means whenever I release the mouse button, the image goes back to the unepressed button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `JButton`, set the standard and pressed icons.